# Checking sql constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a question about constraints in SQL, to be exact in transact-sql. I have a database for trips. I created a procedure for adding new trip participant. I am using ms-sql server so foreign key and primary key constraints were added when I created tables. Now in my procedure for adding new participant for a trip I have

```
insert VoyageThemes(VoyageId,ThemeId) values (@voyageId,@themeId)
```

now, in VoyageThemes table both VoyageId and ThemeId are primary keys and foreign keys, so when I try to add new values that doesen't correspond to already existing values in database constraint raises it's head.

My question is, can I somehow check if constraint 'said' that I can't add values to table, so I can stop the procedure or I need to manually check in my database if VoyageId and ThemeId exists.

I need to know if those values exists because of this line of code:

```
update Voyages
set Voyages.Price=Voyages.Price+@costOfTheme*@numOfParticipants
```

I am updating the price of a trip, so this line of code can only excecute only if there is a corresponding VoyageId and ThemeId

Comment: I believe you can check @@ROWCOUNT after insert to see if it was succesfull.

Comment: Take a look http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/11/01/sql-server-query-to-display-foreign-key-relationships-and-name-of-the-constraint-for-each-table-in-database/ . It has all information you needed (you may also want to add `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.UPDATE_RULE,REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.DELETE_RULE` to the original query)

Comment: Where are you getting the values that you are trying to insert into this table? It looks like you have a Theme table with PK themeId and a Voyage table with PK voyageId and VoyageThemes is a join or many-to-many table. In most applications, you'd have some kind of screen where you'd be picking from a list of existing Themes and or Voyages when you're adding one or the other or linking the two together, in which case your middle app layer at least would know the correct PK ID's to submit to your database...so is it possible your question is indicative of a larger application design issue?

Comment: Those values are passed to my procedure for adding new trip participant, for now I don't have any large application, I just started writing procedures, and this is my first database, so I am a bit lost with all those new things, that's why I asked about errors from constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use a try/catch?:

```
...
BEGIN TRY  
    insert VoyageThemes(VoyageId,ThemeId) values (@voyageId,@themeId)     
    -- If we are here, then the insert succeeded, proceed with the update
    update Voyages
    set Voyages.Price=Voyages.Price+@costOfTheme*@numOfParticipants
    ...
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH  
    -- insert failed, check error
    SELECT @error_number = ERROR_NUMBER(),
           @error_severity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
           @error_state = ERROR_STATE()  
    IF @error_number = 547
    -- constraint violation   
        BEGIN     
            PRINT '...'   
        END  
    ELSE 
        -- propagate error 
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR(@error_number, @error_severity, @error_state) WITH LOG   
        END 
END CATCH
```

Comment: That would cause the `UPDATE` to fail. In case of a pre-existing row, I think they want to just "fail over" the `INSERT` and allow the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @onedaywhen I don't think so, I think they want to update the voyage price *only if the theme is new*. Otherwise, the theme price would be included in the voyage price already.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `INSERT`, use `MERGE` to create a row only if it does not already exists e.g.

```
MERGE INTO VoyageThemes
   USING (
          VALUES (@voyageId, @themeId)
         ) AS S (VoyageId, ThemeId)
      ON VoyageThemes.VoyageId = S.VoyageId
         AND VoyageThemes.ThemeId = S.ThemeId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (VoyageId, ThemeId)
      VALUES (VoyageId, ThemeId);
```